# How can I make sure/test that my notebook build-in video/camera on top of the display  isn't recording?

Tags: 11.10, video, camera

I just want to remove the duck-tape from it to fix this insecurity. Shell commands are welcome, too. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep the duck tape.

(Or remove the driver, see lsmod for the name.)